# Placing headline after text - SEO influence?

Tags: seo, accessibility

There is an element with image - text - headline, placed in a column flex. The headline (h3) is displayed underneath the text. Does it have a negative impact for screen readers or SEO? I'm thinking, someone using a screen reader jumps to the headline and maybe doesn't know that the corresponding text is placed above the headline.

I can't change the design, so would a good approach be putting the elements in reverse order and using a column-reverse flex?